# How to Reference JS file into Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I am trying to use jquery in my marketing cloud prog. I have created .js zip file and uploaded into portfolio but i don't know exactly how to reference it in prog
Any Help will be really appreciated
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upload the .js (not zip) into portlio / contents and copy the link address from its properties.

After you have done this, you would then call it as you would call any .js file in the head tag.

Alternatively you can copy the whole js file and dump it in the header tag.